# Trying to get Count single value from mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to do a count in a mysql stored procedure but cant get the syntax right help1

```
    delimiter//
create procedure get_count_workmen_type(
    IN employee_payroll int,    
    OUT mycount int
)


begin 

SELECT count(*) into mycount from workman
where employee_payroll = employee_payroll

end //
delimiter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefix your parameter names (personally I use "p_") to differentiate them from column names, etc. For example `where employee_payroll = employee_payroll` will always be true because it's comparing the column to itself.

Also you should add a semi-colon to the end of your select statement.

Putting those two changes together gives you something like this:

```
delimiter //

create procedure get_count_workmen_type(
    IN p_employee_payroll int,    
    OUT p_mycount int
)
begin 
  SELECT count(*) 
  into p_mycount 
  from workman
  where employee_payroll = p_employee_payroll;
end //

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Genius thanks! im new to mysql - so used to sql server